# Grid width in Boostrap Angular UI vertical side tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I uses Bootstrap Angular UI vertical tabs. Based on the doc, i got following code

```
<tabset vertical="true" type="pills">
    <tab>
        <tab-heading>
             Heading
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
            <p>You are awesome</p>
        </div>
    </tab>
    <tab>
        <tab-heading>
             Heading 2
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

I would like to have vertical side bar in the left side and main content in the right side. I wanted to set `col-sm-3` to tab heading and `col-sm-9` to the tab content. How do i set those values in Angular UI bootstrap tab?